# How to optimize the overall processing time in this code?

Tags: python, string, list

I have written a code for take set of documents as a list and take another set of words as a list then if in each document check whether any word containing from the list of words and i make sentences from available words

```
//find whether the whole word in the sentence- return None if its not in.
def findWholeWord(w):
  return re.compile(r'\b({0})\b'.format(w), flags=re.IGNORECASE).search



for data in dataset['abc']:
  mvc = ''
  for x in newdataset['Words']:
    y = findWholeWord(x)(data)
    if y != None:
      mvc = mvc+" "+ x

  document.append(mvc)
```

when i run this code for 10000 documents with average word count of 10 , it take like so long time . How to optimize this code? or possible alternatives for this code to do the same functionality

Comment: [profile it](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html), and see which step is taking up all of the time.

Comment: If you're opening 10,000 files, just that might be the issue. I would suggest running it just opening and closing the files, and doing nothing with them. See if that takes just as long.

Comment: @will actually i am opening a dataset which contain all the documents as a csv file .

Comment: If you want to use compiled regexp, you should compile it one time. Not on every call.

Answer (score 1):

Since you just want to check if a word exists in the set of `abc`, you don't need to use `re`.

```
for raw_data in dataset['abc']:
  data = raw_data.lower()
  mvc = ''
  for x in newdataset['Words']:
    if x not in data:
      mvc = mvc+" "+ x

  document.append(mvc)
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that these code works slow? I am not. I think most time you spend opening files. You need to profile your code as Will says. Also you can use [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) to improve speed of your code.